# Single long axon vs serial neurons

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology

*Based on the comments in [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/can-a-single-axon-propagate-multiple-simultaneous-action-potentials/22015#comment41492_22015) post and also [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19544/long-axons-vs-serial-neurons) chat. For discussions and speculations please comment in the chat.*

The basic question is what is the advantage of having a single long axon such as that of sciatic nerve (~1m) compared to a series of neurons?

The primary advantage is surely the conduction speed which will get affected because of chemical synapses. However, gap junction synapses can reduce that delay. The larger volume of the soma of the post synaptic neuron may also reduce the conduction speed, but signal strengthening can also happen. Cell architecture can be adjusted to minimize the loss of speed.

The obvious disadvantage of having a single large cell is that there would be tremendous burden on the nucleus for the cellular maintenance. There would be delays in transfer of non-electrical signals such as biomolecules from axon termini to soma and vice versa. Long axons also means continuous transport along them which in turn demands large number of molecular motors and therefore ATP. Moreover, a small injury can disable the entire conduction channel. It can be imagined that this trait (long axons) can also be selected against; injury leading to inability to move and thereby causing perishment.

**EDIT** (*Based on comments to Anne's answer*)

Time is of course a valid advantage for having a single axon as an information conduction channel. However, the energy or the maintenance cost is the factor that I am actually interested in. Maintenance cost would increase with cell volume (in fact surface area) and having serial neurons would demand more energy (cumulative) than a single axon (including costs of maintaining a nucleus). However a long cell would need much higher number of molecular motors to maintain the traffic flow rate. All responses that require transcriptional control would be slow (such as response to injury). Moreover a single soma also imposes a limit on the number of mitochondria. There should be a limit on how long an axon can be. I am especially interested in case of big animals (with long hindlimbs) that also have a good reflex (perhaps camels, even horses).

Has someone tried to analyse the tradeoffs of having a long axon vs series of neurons connected by gap junctions? If not is this problem worth modeling or quite trivial?

---

*Saw this in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-longest-axon-in-the-world)*:

> My first thought mostly agreed with the question details, except I'm
>   pretty sure that the dorsal root ganglion (DRG) has a longer axon than
>   the motor information carried in the sciatic nerve (which is the
>   longest nerve in the body, but not axon).

*Does this mean that sciatic nerve has serial neurons?*

Comment: Forget conduction speed. What about signal fidelity? How much noise does each extra gap junction add to a signal?

Comment: @tel I am not sure about the noise at the gap junction (GJ). Can you tell me how is noise generated at the GJ?

Comment: I'm not a neruo guy, so I can't give you any specifics, but in terms of general information theory/2nd law considerations, every time you convert a signal from one form to another (axonal current to neurotransmitter gradient, say) your signal/noise ratio gets a little worse. You can recover the original signal somewhat, but it always involves an expense of free energy.

Comment: @tel Oh well.. but in the gap junctions the wave can move to another cell. There are no neurotransmitters involved.

Comment: If you want to reduce the variance in signal transmission with n serial steps, then you need to add more steps. Therefore to achieve signal transmission with really low variance, you either want a single axon (case A) or really lot of them connected in series (case B). May be overall, case A is not so bad compared to case B not to be selected for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I must clarify that a nerve is not the same as a neuron. A nerve is a collection of axons (with each axon a part of an individual neuron) in the peripheral nervous system. Thus, when you mention “single long axon such as the sciatic nerve”, this is technically an incorrect phrase as the sciatic nerve is a collection of many long axons. If one of these axons is nonfunctional, this would not severely affect the function of the entire sciatic nerve. However, you are right that if the entire sciatic nerve is severed, then there would be serious consequences downstream.

Second, the primary advantage of conduction velocity is less dependent on length and more dependent on presence and degree of myelination (directly proportional to fiber diameter) and presence of nodes of Ranvier.

With regards to the content of your question, the advantage of length is exactly what one might think--- greater distance. The sciatic nerve is the longest nerve in the body in order for our nervous system to innervate as far as the tip of our toes. Having hundreds of side-by-side series of neurons compared to hundreds of side-by-side axons seems like a far less efficient system in a couple of ways in exactly the two ways you mention: energy and time.

Energy: Having serial neurons would require an increase the number of neurons needed to transmit a message. Having more neurons requires more Na+, K+ and Na/K pumps and individual channels, requiring more energy.

Time: Having serial neurons would also require an increase in the number of synapses between neurons— either electrical or chemical. If the synapses are chemical, then time is increased many-many fold. If the synapses are electrical, then time is slightly increased by 10-fold per synapse compared to chemical synapses, but this would still take more time compared to having a single axon with myelination and nodes of Ranvier which by about 100-fold faster than a single electrical synapse.

In summary, having longer nerves made up of axons rather than serial neurons is beneficial by improving energy and time efficiency, which allows our bodies to effectively innervate structures farther away.

Ref:

- Regarding delay of conduction: Chemical v. Electrical/Gap  Ch 10 of Principles of Neuroscience- "Synaptic Integration in the Central Nervous System" (Siegelbaum,
  Kandel, Yuste) 5th ed. McGraw-Hill Medical, c2013.
- [Regarding conduction velocity of myelinated versus nonmyelinated
  cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10921/)

Regarding the ATPase absolute number increase in serial vs one long axon, I assume this will depend on the number of neurons in series. However, I read [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23022068), which says that increased length between each node of Ranvier has been physiologically associated with increased conduction velocity. This suggests fewer needed nodes, despite concentrated ATPases at these locations, and thus fewer ATPases. I haven't been able to find studies which compare ATPase concentration in the soma compared to nodes of Ranvier within axons.

Regarding energy use in soma vs axon, mitochondria are not only made in the soma but are concentrated in pre- and post-synaptic membranes (and growth cones). The more of these structures there are (as in serial neurons), the more presumed mitochondria. See [mitochondria and neuronal activity](http://ajpcell.physiology.org/content/292/2/C641).

Finally, my literature search could not find studies which showed longest possible energetically feasible length for myelinated or unmyelinated neurons.

Comment: Why would multiple neurons need more ATPases? The only difference is more cell bodies? Could you provide a citation for the gap junction transduction velocity? I would think it would be about as fast as myelinated conduction. If I am wrong than this is a likely answer!

Comment: @ChrisStronks I will add references tomorrow, I used quite a few so it will take time.

Comment: @ChrisStronks Multiple neruons need more ATPs as they will have other soma related function to which they have to cater to. More soma=more protoplasm=More volume of space where electrolyte balance need to be maintained=More channels active=More ATP

Comment: @Anne "*primary advantage of conduction velocity is not dependent on length*".. yes I meant in the context of uninterrupted myelinated axon. And length does have a role in velocity (see cable equation). Your point on time is correct but I am slightly skeptical about the energy part. What about larger animals; would there be an optimal length of a single axon?

Comment: @ChrisStronks Besides, energy is expended for other cell functions - facultative and constitutive cell functions which would not be expended otherwise

Comment: @CRags Requirement of ATP is more or less related to total volume of the cell which would be slightly more in case of serial neurons but not overwhelmingly high. Also a long cell would need much higher number of molecular motors to maintain the traffic flow rate. All responses that require transcriptional control would be slow (such as response to injury).

Comment: We are not talking about responses though. Purely from a energy point of view, more cells=more energy expenditure. The longer length of the axon does not mean more molecular motor. As the organ/part which is ennervated is at a fixed distance, one neuron or multiple neuron would have the same number of molecular motors. Infact in this scenario, multiple neurons would require more energy than a single neuron due to the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: What I would grant you is the time taken to resolve any disruptions. This would be undisputably longer for longer neurons

Comment: @WYSIWYG With neurons, diameter plays a much larger role than length. [Nernst Potential and Nerve Conduction Speed](http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En123/Lectures/electroN.htm)

Comment: @Anne Did not discredit that. Was just saying that length does have a role :) And yes with the introduction of another soma the diameter will change; however increase in diameter is favorable for longitudinal current (as resistivity is constant; conductance ∝ Area); the problem is the case of less insulation i.e low transverse resistance leading to leaks. In any case I accept that time is an obvious advantage. My question is would energy be a tradeoff at some point: single soma also imposes a limit on number of mitochondria.

Comment: @Anne I am also confused here: myelination directly proportional to diameter. Can you provide a link for this; Do schwann cells have a limit on how much can they extend (the coiling during myelination). Of course they cannot myelinate the soma but this is still an interesting point. However I guess there can be ways to reduce membrane resistance without myelination- perhaps by having anchored cytoplasmic domains to confine the leak channels (this can be regulated at the soma). This is just my guess. I think I am raising too many arguments; forgive me I don't have much knowledge of this area.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Myelination + axon cross section = fiber diameter.  This applies only of course if we are talking about myelinated neurons. If you have a non-myelinated neuron, axon = fiber diameter. See [yellow and green picture](http://www.uic.edu/classes/bios/bios100/lecturesf04am/lect22.htm) on the bottom the page.

Comment: @WYSIWYG [Mitochondria and neuronal activity](http://ajpcell.physiology.org/content/292/2/C641). You make a good point about limitation of mitochondria based on capacity of a neuron, and it is unknown whether more neurons in series would require overall less mitochondria than a long axon of a single neuron. However, the references states that mitochondria are not only made in the soma but are concentrated in pre- and post-synaptic membranes (and growth cones). The more of these structures there are (as in serial neurons), the more presumed mitochondria.

Comment: @Anne I understand the point about the fiber diameter and myelination. I thought you meant (in the answer) that extent of myelination is dependent on diameter of the axon. Yes mitochondria are localized in axon termini and are transported there via axons. I meant that neuron in series can accommodate more mitochondria to cope up with energy demands. Single soma would be overburdened. Sorry for asking another question: what is the longest axon known. I want to know till point having a single axon would be be an optimal solution (beyond which it is infeasible).

Comment: @WYSIWYG Longest axon in humans belongs to the neurons of the sciatic nerve, though some debate it's the DRG. In the world, probably the same structures in a blue whale or other creature we may not have discovered. How long can it get before it is not energetically feasible? That's an experiment yet to be done. Diameter was meant in context of fiber, not axon.

Comment: @Anne Can you add these points in the answer. I can accept it then. So I guess the question "*How long can it get before it is not energetically feasible*" is worth pursuing, at least theoretically. You sure there are no theoretical studies on this?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I edited my answer, hopefully that helps. As far as I have searched in pubmed, google scholar, etc haven't been able to find studies regarding energetic feasibility, unfortunately. Please let me know if you have any other questions.